# Python3 client socket received message not complete

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to send commands to my remote server using Python sockets. My remote server is listening on port 50000 (server socket is not configured with python). When I log onto the server and echo the command I want I get the correct results back as followed:

```
echo mycommand | nc 127.0.0.1 50000
```

I get back three lines to stdout:

```
>ServerOn=
>Command_received
>Cmd=mycommand
```

I want to achieve the same on the client side using python3. I know Iam able to connect to the server, however, I am not getting the full response like above. I tried the following:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('myhost', 50000))
s.sendall('mycommand')
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print(repr(data))
```

but I only get back the first line

```
>ServerOn=
```

Any ideas why I am missing part of the response?

Comment: Did you try: `echo mycommand | nc 127.0.0.1 50000 - `  (note ending `-`)   Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/261900/how-can-i-pipe-commands-to-a-netcat-that-will-stay-alive

Comment: @Kingsley Yeah, that works too, the problem i am having is with Python not netcat though, I want my Python code to return the same output as my netcat. So far it is only returning the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The socket `recv()` returns when a chunk of data has arrived.  There's no guarantee on what size that chunk is, other than that it's less than the passed size, `1024` in this case.  Here it looks like the client has sent part of the data when it saw an end-of-line.

If you want to check/parse what you have received, it will be necessary to read it into a buffer until you have the amount of data you expect.

In the short term, keep reading until the socket closes:

```
    connected = True
    while connected:
        data = s.recv(2048)
        if not data:
            connected = False
            print("### Client Disconnected")
        else:
            print("Received data: %u octets" % (len(data)))
            try:
                as_string = str(data,'utf-8')
                print(as_string)
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work, it still only returned the first line `Received data: 13 octets; >ServerOn=`. I tried using netcat from a different host to see if it is a firewall issue but it works `echo mycommand | nc my_host 50000`. For some reason, the python sockets only return back the first line... Is it cause my server is not using python as the code base?